# Можно ли на js получить число от - до +?

Tags: javascript

с помощью Math.random() нужно получить число между отрицательным и положительным числом. Это возможно?

Comment: Числа целые? Или вещественные?

Comment: и то и другое. Без разницы мне главное как это сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам нужен интервал от -1 до 1, используйте это:

```
Math.random()*2-1
```

После умножения интервала от 0 до 1 на 2, получится случайное число между 0 и 2. Осталось вычесть единицу и получить случайное число между -1 и 1.
Если вам нужен интервал от -n до n, то используйте это:

```
(Math.random()*2-1)*n
```

Comment: В конце -1 это сдвиг?

Comment: @Dias да это сдвиг

Answer (score 2):

Ну тут надо подумать.

Math.random() даёт интервал 0..1, а нужно интервал размером (XMax - XMin). Значит, нужно умножить случайное число на (XMax - XMin). Получается случайное число в интервале 0..(XMax - XMin)

А теперь надо сдвинуть этот интервал, добавив нижний предел. Итого выходит

```
X = Math.random() *  (XMax - XMin) + XMin
```

Пример для диапазона -2..8:

```
X = Math.random() *  (8 - (-2)) + (-2) = 
    Math.random() * 10  -  2
```

Comment: X = Math.random() * (Xmin - Xmax) + Xmax я получил желаемые числа только в таком виде

Comment: Для случая, когда XMin=-XMax, эти формулы дают одинаковый результат, но в общем случае (например, вам понадобится диапазон от -2 до +8) ваша формула **неверная**.  А в вашем вопросе не сказано, что XMin=-XMax (например, -5 и 5)

Answer (score 1):

Генерация случайного вещественного числа в интервале *[a, b)*:

```
const randomInRange = (a, b) => Math.random() * (b - a) + a;
```